# R extract lat and lon from a google maps URL

Tags: r, stringr

I have this string from a google maps URL:

```
link <- c("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=19.435559,-99.193512&zoom=12&size=672x336&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAqyNnLAfVROybp1jk2dmHfFgkoV4esyoI&signature=YwfgjHhGS2TC_XpbMhBt9hJcgLw=")
```

I'd like to extract the lat and lon and save it to a data frame using the stringr package for R, but I don't know how to do it.

Anybody has a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming ou want the "19.435559,-99.193512", maybe something like : str_extract(link, "-?\\d+\\.\\d+,-?\\d+\\.\\d+"), this would give you that string, then of course you'd have to split it into columns

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_match` from `stringr` to extract lat and lon in 2 columns :

```
link <- c("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=19.435559,-99.193512&zoom=12&size=672x336&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAqyNnLAfVROybp1jk2dmHfFgkoV4esyoI&signature=YwfgjHhGS2TC_XpbMhBt9hJcgLw=")

stringr::str_match(link, 'center=(-?\\d+\\.\\d+),(-?\\d+\\.\\d+)')[, -1, drop = FALSE]

#            [,1]        [,2]        
#[1,] "19.435559" "-99.193512"
```